# Javascript If variable value type

Tags: javascript

I have the following function which populates  elements options.

```
player.onTracksChanged_ = function(event) {
  // Update the track lists.
  var lists = {
    video: document.getElementById('videoTracks'),
    audio: document.getElementById('audiotrackButton'),
    text: document.getElementById('captionButton')
  };
  var formatters = {
    video: function(track) {
      return track.width + 'x' + track.height + ', ' +
             track.bandwidth + ' bits/s';
    },
    audio: function(track) {
      return 'language: ' + track.language + ', ' +
         track.bandwidth + ' bits/s';
    },
    text: function(track) {
      return 'language: ' + track.language + ' ' +
         '(' + track.kind + ')';
    }
  };

  // Clear the old track lists.
  Object.keys(lists).forEach(function(type) {
    var list = lists[type];
    while (list.firstChild) {
      list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
    }
  });

  // Populate with the new tracks.
  var tracks = player.getTracks();
  tracks.sort(function(t1, t2) {
    // Sort by language, then by bandwidth.
    if (t1.language) {
      var ret = t1.language.localeCompare(t2.language);
      if (ret) return ret;
    }
    return t1.bandwidth - t2.bandwidth;
  });
  tracks.forEach(function(track) {
    var list = lists[track.type];
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = formatters[track.type](track);
    option.track = track;
    option.value = track.id;
    option.selected = track.active;
    list.appendChild(option);
  });
};
```

What I am trying to achieve is an if statement based on this which determines if the number of each 'type' of 'track' is greater than or equal to 2, this is what I've got:-

```
            var mediaTracks = player.getTracks();               
            if (mediaTracks.length >= 2) {
                console.log('there are more than 2 tracks');
            } else {
                console.log('there are less than 2 tracks');
            };
```

When in fact I need to do something more like this:-

```
var mediaTracksVideo = player.getTracks(video)
var mediaTracksAudio = player.getTracks(audio)
```

Then do something like:-
    if (mediaTracksAudio >= 2) {...

But when I try player.getTracks(audio); the console logs 'audio is not defined'.

Any idea why?

Comment: I think it must be `formatters.audio` or `lists.audio`, not only `audio` in the parameter

Comment: I thinks formatters.audio() would be fine as audio is defined as function

Comment: Actually, possibly what's wanted is `player.getTracks('audio')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried formatters.audio and lists.audio like this:-

    var audioTrackList = player.getTracks(formatters.audio); However, I get formatters/lists is undefined error. I then tried player.getTracks(audio) which again, audio is undefined. Then player.getTracks('audio') which returned 12 - which is the total number of tracks (of all types, not just audio).

Answer (score 1):

With player.getTracks(audio) you're using the variable audio, which is undefined. You probably want to use player.getTracks('audio'), where 'audio' is a string.

Comment: I think this is heading more in the right direction, however, using var audioTrackList = player.getTracks('audio'); does not seem to return only the tracks of type 'audio' but all tracks (I expect the console to log 8, but returns 12 - which is inclusive of all video, audio and text tracks.

Comment: You'll need to update your question to get an answer to this, because there is no definition of getTracks() listed in your post.

Comment: The getTracks() function is very convoluted, here's the documentation for it:- https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/shakaExtern.html#Track Incidentally if specify id numbers and the 'type' then these do log correctly, reporting id 0 is 'video' type and track 4 is 'audio' type. So there's that. Eg. 

console.log('got the tracks...' + tracks[0]['type'] + ', ' + tracks[4]['type'] + ', etc...');